# LinqToExcel Can't read all rows

Tags: linq-to-excel

I use LinqToExcel to read an Excel file in my C# console app. However it only reads the first 254 rows and ignores the rest. How to troubleshoot what's wrong?

Comment: Show us the code you're using?

Comment: using (var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(srcFile))
{
    excel.ReadOnly = true;
    var employees = from x in excel.WorksheetRange<MyData>("A2", "AD60000")   select x;
    foreach (MyData r in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", r.ID, r.Name);
    }
}

Comment: Here is the debug message:

2015-08-24 13:31:02,331 [1] DEBUG LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor Connection String: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\data\ALL_ACTIVE_EMP.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
2015-08-24 13:31:02,346 [1] DEBUG LinqToExcel.SQL SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A2:AD59178] WHERE ([SourceAD Domain] = ?); p0 =
'CONTOS';

Comment: Is it possible there was some Jet driver buffer overflow?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code with same spreadsheet, it also only read the first 254 rows:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""", srcFile);
string query = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A2:AD600000] WHERE ([SourceAD Domain] = ""Contos"")", numberOfRows);
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
try
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
}catch (Exception ex){
    logger.Error(ex);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of *numberOfRows*? Actually, did you try using it since it used to be there? Maybe you're running into some default row limit now.

Comment: numberOfRows = 592000.